# variant where middle 4 squares aren't used

Tags: chess-variants

A teacher of mine proposed a chess variant to me that he called "border chess," where the middle four squares (d4, d5, e4, and e5) cannot be used. In other words, no piece can occupy one of those 4 squares, and no long range piece can pass through them (eg a bishop cannot go from b2 to g7, since it would entail passing through d4 and e5). What do you think?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you really mean by "What do you think"? This way it looks like an opinion-based question.

Comment: You could ask for ideas helping to stabilize the variation or examples where it behaves right, or examples which could deem the variation unplayable.